# ruby create an apartment tenant with a button in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I've just create a new app with users (devise) and a model entreprise (a user could have many entreprise).
This model entreprise has an attribute called subdomain. Each subdomain will have a tenant in Apartment

I would not like to create the tenant when user create Entreprise. I would like to have a listing views of Entreprise"In this view there should be a button to create tenant (after checking if tenant does not already exists).

thanks for your help as I m newbie in rails...

Comment: I tried this but not working

Comment: in the view I tried this <% if Tenant.where(subdomain: entreprise.subdomain).exists?%> but it seems not working

Comment: Could you please share the code you have so far

Comment: Add your code please. It's very unclear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking how to create a tenant with the click of the button? If that's the case, you can just make it a simple link:

**view**

```
<%= link_to "add new tenant", create_tenant_path(enterprise: enterprise), method: :post %>
```

**routes**

```
post 'create_tenant/:enterprise' => 'tenants#create', as: 'tenant'
```

**controller**

```
...
def create
  Tenant.create(enterprise_id: params[:enterprise])
  redirect_to enterprise_path(params[:enterprise])
end
```

Or did I misunderstand what you're trying to do?